# Conditional validation

Tags: validation, cakephp

My HotelAddress Model:

```
<?php

class HotelAddress extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'HotelAddress';
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Hotel' => array(
            'className' => 'Hotel'
        )
    );

    var $validate = array(
        'address' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        )
    );
```

My HotelModel

```
<?php

class Hotel extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Hotel';
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'HotelCategory' => array(
            'className' => 'HotelCategory'
        )
    );
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Page' => array(
            'className' => 'Page'
        )
    );
    var $hasMany = array(
        'HotelAddress' => array(
            'className' => 'HotelAddress',
            'dependent' => TRUE
        ),
        'HotelPhone' => array(
            'className' => 'HotelPhone',
            'dependent' => TRUE
        )
    );
```

My View:

```
<div id="main">
        <h2>Add Hotel</h2>
        <?php echo $this->Session->flash();?>
        <div>
        <?php
        echo $this->Form->create('Hotel');
        echo $this->Form->input('Hotel.name');
        echo $this->Form->input('HotelCategory', array('options' => $hotel_categories, 'multiple' => 'checkbox'));
        echo $this->Form->input('HotelAddress.0.address');
        echo $this->Form->input('HotelAddress.1.address');
        echo $this->Form->input('HotelAddress.2.address');
        echo $this->Form->input('HotelPhone.0.phone');
        echo $this->Form->input('Page.meta_keywords');
        echo $this->Form->input('Page.meta_description');

        echo $this->Form->end('Save Hotel');
        ?>
        </div>
<!-- main ends -->
</div>
```

My problem is that I don't need to validate the other `HotelAddress`es. If the user fills up at least one of the addresses, it should validate. However, if he doesn't fill up any, an error should show.

I believe I should be adding code on the `beforeSave` method but I don't have an idea on what should be there to do this.

**Update:**

I now have this in the HotelAddress Model which works by not validating the existence of the other addresses if one is available. However, it still saves.

```
var $existing_address = FALSE;
var $validate = array(
    'address' => array(
        'rule' => 'checkOnce',
    )
);

function checkOnce($check) {
    if (isset($this->data['HotelAddress']['address'])) {
        if (! empty($this->data['HotelAddress']['address'])) {
            return $this->existing_address = TRUE;
        } else {
            unset($this->data['HotelAddress']['address']);
            return $this->existing_address;
        }
    }
    return $this->existing_address;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd simply go with this in the controller before calling `save`:

```
if (empty($this->data['HotelAddress'][1]['address'])) {
    unset($this->data['HotelAddress'][1]['address']);
}
if (empty($this->data['HotelAddress'][2]['address'])) {
    unset($this->data['HotelAddress'][2]['address']);
}
```

Comment: This is almost what I did. Although I did it a loop since addresses will be generated by javascript so I wouldn't know how many there would be.

Answer (score 1):

Why not take control of the validation away from Model, and code it yourself? You could do the validation in a beforeSave method or in a method that is called before you call the save method, viz:

```
if($this->validateForm($this->data))
{
    $this->Hotel->saveAll($this->data);
}
```

Comment: It's actually difficult to do it in the beforeSave since each `address` is validated one a time. It was difficult to keep track of which `address` to unset and check the other `address`es. +1 close enough.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do the checking in the `beforeSave` because you'll lose a lot of Cake's built in validation magic with forms and such.

You can create a [custom validation](http://book.cakephp.org/view/150/Custom-Validation-Rules) method in your model that will return `boolean` to indicate success of the check. In there you will have access to the data for the model via `$this->data` and you can check for the existence of at least one address.

Comment: Yes. This was my other option.